# Error on std::pair when compiling for mac / linux

Tags: c++, windows, macos, compiler-construction, std

I have a problem when compiling my code under Mac OS. This function declaration in my header file apparently causes some errors (it does work fine under Windows, though):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#ifdef WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

[...]

    int setProcessEnvironment(
        const wchar_t * procName,
        const wchar_t * appName = NULL,
        const wchar_t * workingDir = NULL,
        const wchar_t * cmdArgs = NULL,
        const std::vector< std::pair<const wchar_t *, int> > &systemEnvVars = std::vector< std::pair<const wchar_t *, int> >()
    );
```

It looks like the compiler doesn't like the input for my pair - maybe I am missing some includes or what is the problem here?

I also don't fully understand the last line of this error message as my function description actually looks very different to the one in this error...

I am starting to think it may have to do with the default initialization, but what is the difference between the Mac and Windows compiler here?

```
26: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘>’ token
26: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:68: error: provided for ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair’
26: error: template argument 1 is invalid
26: error: template argument 2 is invalid
26: error: default argument missing for parameter 6 of ‘int SysProcManager::setProcessEnvironment(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const std::vector<std::pair<const wchar_t*, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const wchar_t*, int> > >&, int)’
159: error: prototype for ‘int SysProcManager::setProcessEnvironment(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const std::vector<std::pair<const wchar_t*, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const wchar_t*, int> > >&)’ does not match any in class ‘SysProcManager’
26: error: candidates are: int SysProcManager::setProcessEnvironment(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const std::vector<std::pair<const wchar_t*, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const wchar_t*, int> > >&, int)
138: error:                 int SysProcManager::setProcessEnvironment(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, const std::vector<const wchar_t*, std::allocator<const wchar_t*> >&)
```

Comment: You error seems to have something to do to with the function's invocation. Can you tell us where is line 26?

Comment: I included line 26 in the small code example above - it's the header file's declaration of this function

Comment: What do you plan on doing with a `const` reference to an empty vector?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you `typedef std::vector< std::pair<const wchar_t*,int> > EnvironmentBlock;` (change the name to your liking). Replace the two instances in your function declaration. See if that clears up any parsing errors.

Comment: What compiler version are you using on the Mac?

Comment: Are you sure you've pasted the same function prototype as the one throwing the error? In the code above `SysProcManager::setProcessEnvironment()` takes 5 parameters, but the error message complains about "default argument missing for parameter 6" for the same function. The message also indicates an `int` parameter at the end that your prototype is missing. Or maybe you've got the extra parameter listed in the implementation file but not in the header?

Comment: @Charles - I need a default initialization of that vector - sometimes I don't want to have to give it any input in that variable

Comment: @Andre - yeah I can try that - thank you

Comment: @Michael I think the default compiler is still gcc 4.2 - not the latest version I guess, maybe I should update that...

Comment: @Praetorian - yeah thanks - that is exactly the problem, the error message tells me I would have 6 parameters, which I don't as you can see in the declaration - I am only using 5 parameters, but somehow the compiler seems to screw up here...

Comment: @Chris: I've run into trouble with cross platform code throwing compiler errors on MSVC depending on whether the compiler option to treat `wchar_t` as a native type is set or not. Could this be something similar? Is it possible for you to change all the `const wchar_t *` to `const std::wstring&` (after including `<string>`)? Or to `const std::wstring::value_type *`, though I'm not sure whether this would make any difference to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was pointed out by André Caron:

> Out of curiosity, can you typedef
>   std::vector< std::pair > EnvironmentBlock;
>   (change the name to your liking).
>   Replace the two instances in your
>   function declaration. See if that
>   clears up any parsing errors.

I am now declaring `typedef std::vector< std::pair<const wchar_t*, int> > EnvironmentBlock;` at the beginning and it does solve this problem on the Mac and it seems the compiler just can't deal with these nested types properly and screws things up - I did not see this problem on Linux or Windows, so maybe it's time to update my compiler (GCC 4.2).

Thank you Andre!

Answer (score 2):

Try `#include <utility>`

Comment: I think `#include <map>` should get you `std::pair`, since it needs `std::pair`.  But I can't see anything else wrong here...

Comment: @Charles: `std::pair` should be defined in `<utility>`

Comment: @UncleBens, I know, but the OP is #including `<map>`, and `<map>` must use `std::pair`, so I don't think it's possible that the OP's problem is that the compiler can't find the definition for `std::pair`.

Comment: And bits/stl_pair.h, the g++-specific file defining `std::pair`, was mentioned, so the definition has certainly been seen.

Comment: @Charles: I'd argue that you should always include the header that a class is supposed to be defined in. Depending on dependencies like "`<map>` should include `std::pair`" might land you in trouble when switching compilers. Maybe some compiler has found a way to forward declare `std::pair` within the `<map>` header and do the actual inclusion only in the `std::map` implementation file. I know this is probably not possible with template code but it is safer to just include the required headers explicitly.

Comment: @Praetorian, I agree.  However, I'm just pointing out that in this particular case, a failure to find the definition of `std::pair` is very, very likely not the problem.

Comment: @Charles: I agree with that assessment too, especially because of the error message contents as @aschepler pointed out.

Comment: yeah - I agree with Charles, the std::pair can be found, but the default initialization seems to screw up things here & including utility unfortunately didn't make any difference...

Comment: Sorry this didn't help.  Admittedly, it was a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the errors relate to the fact you have 2 definitions of setProcessEnvironment.  One that takes as an added int on the end and another that takes in  vector of wchar_t (not a vector of pairs).

I'd focus on these 2 problems to begin with.  Failing that we need to see the rest of the code because some of the errors are being generated by code we can't see.

Comment: yes, there are two declarations of this function, but there is none with an added int at the end... the compiler only thinks this is the case and my question was how to resolve this - sorry, if the question wasn't that clear - but non of these points is a real problem as I can overload my function as many times as I like

Comment: @Chris: And NEITHER matches what you have posted above according to the compiler errors.  Can we see the rest of the code please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but clearly that's the question: Why can't the compiler properly interpret my function declaration..? I think it is not really required to see more code and the problem was solved (please see the message I quoted from Andre above)

Comment: @Chris:  I don't know ... post up the rest of the code and I might be able to help!

Comment: thanks - using a "typedef std::vector< std::pair > EnvironmentBlock;" works fine for now